# copying iptables to ip6tables

Tags: debian, iptables, ipv6

Is it possible to copy the iptables ipv4 rules to iptables ipv6? I already tried to just copy them to ipv6, but it doesn't really work. Most outgoing and incoming connections doesn't work. Maybe there are some problems about ipv4 addresses like localhost or cloudflare ip's

My ipv4 settings: https://hastebin.com/otayisaroj

Comment: How are you coping them?

Answer (score 2):

Your basic firewall rules only include application ports and not addresses, so they should work for both IPv4 and IPv6. What is wrong is your filtering of ICMPv6 packets. You now filter all of them, and that breaks IPv6. ICMPv6 (note: different protocol than ICMPv4) is crucial to the operation of IPv6.

The easiest option is probably to use one of the firewall tools that come with the system as they will take this into account. If you want to write your own rules then I recommend taking a look at [RFC 4890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4890) which explains in detail what you should consider.